# Pachyderm deploy GCP - no such image

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, pachyderm

I'm deploying Pachyderm on GKE but when I deploy the pipeline (following the https://docs.pachyderm.com/latest/getting_started/beginner_tutorial/) the Pod fails in ImagePullCrashLoopBack giving this error "no such image".

Here, the output of the command "kubectl get pods":
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpvj7.png)

How can I fix the deployment procedure?

Comment: Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Slack channel of Pachyderm community, adding the flag `--no-expose-docker-socket` to the deploy call should solve the issue.

`pachctl deploy google ${BUCKET_NAME} ${STORAGE_SIZE} --dynamic-etcd-nodes=1 --no-expose-docker-socket`

Comment: You're right, my Pod wasn't able to access the external container repository,